# JavaScript restart canvas script

Tags: javascript

I have a canvas script written in `<script>` tag in HTML body, with global variables. It include the game code. Now I want to add some restart option (for example when player die, restart the game). How can I reload all things/main script? I tried to remove `<canvas>` tag from HTML and add it again, but the game animation (after that) stops and it shows the first keyframe  (which is visible after game restart) is the last one from the game before.
At the moment the only way for me is location.reload(), but it's a really bad solution.

So the question is - is there any way to restart whole script? I want to make it work like after page reload (default everything). I can use only pure JavaScript.

Thank you for help.

Comment: If you rely on global variables then add a `startGame()` function that sets all of those global variables back to their default/starting values. You'd then call `startGame()` both when the page first loads (to set up the first game) and after games end (to set up subsequent games).

Answer (score 1):

Try making the different aspects of the game in functions which call each other. You can have for example an init() function which you call on `$document.ready()` (import the jquery library from [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery) ). When the player dies, clear the canvas with `context.clearRect ( x , y , w , h );` and call init() again.