# How to restart a canvas without reload

Tags: javascript, canvas, meteor, three.js, webgl

**I simply want to restart a canvas on a website. I do not want to reload the page, so the restart has to be done dynamically. Problem : after few restarts the animation gets slower and the memory increases.**

Actually i face a more complex situation : I use a javascript framework to load pages, MeteorJS with IronRouter. Changing the URL only changes the DOM (nodes are removed) but the 'page' is not really left. So i thought that coming back to my page with the canvas can be assimilated to a dynamic canvas restart, since i have no solution to that too.

That is why i describe the problem from two points of view (same problem on both) :

1. first a simple page where a button asks the canvas to restart
2. then applying the solution to MeteorJS with IronRouter and try to come back on my page many times.

Note : my canvas content is some WebGL (in ThreeJS).

---

### **1. Deleting and re-initializing canvas dynamically.**

In this case i face those two problems :

- animation not smooth
- memory increase. To be precise :

[image: Memory use]
<sub>(source: [hostingpics.net](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/263473issue.png))</sub>

1. Page loaded, playing with canvas / 2. Restarting the canvas 30-40 times (i did not stop restarting so i do not know why the increase is not linear) / 3. Playing with canvas / 4. Closing the tab (reloading the page only frees a small fraction of what has been mobilized)

Few questions on SO yet asked how to solve those issues, but reproducing the solutions partially solves the problem. I have read two main things :

- the canvas-related parts (nodes, variables, functions) have to be cleaned from the DOM (That is something Meteor does. But in this first part it stays relevant and yet is not enough to prevent the issues).
- if `requestAnimationFrame` has been called, it needs to get assigned to a variable so `cancelAnimationFrame(variable)` can stop it. That indeed seems to prevent the frame rate drop. While memory stays high, at least the movements remain fluent.

With those solutions the memory problem still happens.

Here is an example : http://codepen.io/Astrak/pen/RNYLxd

---

### **2. In MeteorJS : i cannot get this partial solution work.**

Here is what i wrote in my app, with `id=requestAnimationFrame(myAnimation)` declared globaly :

```
 Template.myTemplate.destroyed=function(){
      cancelAnimationFrame(id);
      document.body.removeChild(document.querySelector('canvas'));//useful in Meteor ?
 };
```

Despite those instructions, my animation gets slow much quicker with MeteorJS than in the previous example : it becomes unusable after 3-4 page change. And same memory problem.

Thanks for every comment and answer and happy coding :)

---

Related questions :

[Performance drop on multiple restart of scene from threejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286450/performance-drop-on-multiple-restart-of-scene-from-threejs)

[Performance drops when trying to reset whole scene with Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823408/performance-drops-when-trying-to-reset-whole-scene-with-three-js)

[How do we handle webgl context lost event in Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350350/how-do-we-handle-webgl-context-lost-event-in-three-js)

[Pause, resume and restart Canvas animations with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279776/pause-resume-and-restart-canvas-animations-with-js)

[How can I restart my function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429799/how-can-i-restart-my-function)

[JavaScript restart canvas script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303749/javascript-restart-canvas-script)

Comment: are you checking to make sure that the destroyed function is actually getting called?

Comment: @RamsayLanier indeed none of the two lines are executed :) I don't know why. I used Template.myTemplate.rendered=myFunction; to call the function where id=requestAnimationFrame(animate) appears. I have no clue why the removeChild line does not work too. Meteor's scopes are not clear to me.

Comment: not sure without seeing more of the code - but, you could call cancelAnimationFrame in an IronRouter onBeforeAction() hook so whenever you load a new page it cancels the animation - then when the template renders the animation starts again.

Comment: also, when I've done stuff with Three.js - I typically create a global variable called "animateable" and set it to false, then when a button is clicked it sets it to true. In the animate() function I then do something like if (animateable){ requestAnimationFrame(animate())} - maybe you could set a session variable and achieve the same effect.

Comment: @RamsayLanier i inserted `Router.onBeforeAction(function() {if(typeof id !== 'undefined'){cancelAnimationFrame(id);alert('id deleted')}this.next()});`, no pop up. However i replaced the `id` declaration by your `animatable` variable, set it to false in `myTemplate.destroyed` and added it as a condition in the `animate()` function as you said : no more slow down in the animation ! That is really great, thanks. Remains the huge memory increase, that can saturate the computer after 30-40 restarts

Answer (score 1):

For memory problem, I'd recommend Chrome's javascript profiler - you can compare snapshots before and after canvas is reloaded and see which objects are not freed from memory.

Problem usually comes from event handlers and/or using closures. If you, for example, hook a function to window object's onresize event, all objects referenced in this function will stay in memory as long as window exists. So always remove event handlers from global objects if you want to refresh page content without actually refreshing the browser session.

Similar with closures. They will create link between function's scope and referenced variables preventing GC to collect them. Check this https://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/08/13/an-interesting-kind-of-javascript-memory-leak